# Do "figure out" and "realize" mean the same?

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs

Talking about noticing something, do both mean the same?

For example:

> - I just figured out that the ball is blue.
> - I just realized that the ball is blue.

Comment: What did you find in a dictionary? [Realise](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/realize?q=realise) | [Figure out](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/figure?q=figure+out#figure__41) -- it looks like those definitions could overlap to some extent, even if they are not entirely synonymous. Perhaps you could show your own research.

Comment: @Andrew: The definitions only overlap insofar as in both cases you end up *being aware* of something. But it seems to me it's General Reference that you always have to make a mental effort to *figure something out*, whereas *realise* normally carries no such implication of "directed effort" (in fact, *realisation* often comes completely out of the blue).

Comment: @F Yes, I'm happy that it's General Reference too. The definitions explain exactly what you have enunciated. In the absence of anything more in the question, a single link to a reference work suffices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. They are substantially different.

To realize, in the sense of coming to a conclusion (and not as in to bring into reality, which is akin to inventing something), means to comprehend something completely.

The act of figuring out is the act of finding a solution to a problem.

Realization usually happens unexpectedly, as if by magic. One minute your mind wanders, and then you see something in a new light. In that sense, it's a passive occurrence.

Figuring something out, on the other hand, takes effort, and is normally done with a specific goal in mind.

Comment: I agree. Realizations often come serendipitously, often while doing something not directly related to the question at hand. Figuring out something implies a conscious effort to calculate/investigate/study a matter and actively search for the answer. I may realize that the Israel-Palestine conflict is not easily solvable while watching the news and reading articles (it just "clicks" in the head); on the other hand, I figure out what's wrong with my car by methodically going through a checklist of potential issues and eliminating each one systematically.

Comment: Are they both factive? I.e, can you say _He figured out that the moon is made of green cheese_? You can't say _*He realized that the moon is made of green cheese_ because _realize_ is factive and presupposes its complement. Does _figure out_?